# Nashorn on Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, nashorn

So, Java's Nashorn engine allows to embed javascript in a java application.
Nashorn's javascript has some non-vanilla javascript features, it is possible to write a function litteral like this :

```
function add(x,y)x+y
```

Which is the same as `function add(x,y){return x+y;}`

There is also the for each loop :

```
for each(var i in myArray) print(i)
```

I would like to edit the javascript files in Visual studio code. However, for the features above, since they are not vanilla javascript, VSCode detects an error.
I couldn't find an extension for visual studio to support Nashorn's javascript.

Is there any way to "extend" the javascript support on visual studio to allow the features above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You'd need an extension that implements a Nashorn JS [language server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server). VS Code's built-in JS support cannot be extended easily this way

You can suppress these error messages by setting:

```
 "javascript.validate.enable": false
```

IntelliSense and other language support will still not work however without a proper language extension